# Aligning search-results under search-bar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to work out how to correctly display my search-results directly beneath my search-bar. As of now, the search results are placed a bit to the left of the search bar, and whilst you type and results starts to appear in the list, the search result bar grows. How do i make it so that the search results bar is completely beneath the search bar, and always have a fixed width.
To further improve this solution, i'd be cool if anyone could suggest how you could make the transition more fluent (so that there isn't a black line between the two fields).

HTML:

```
<div class="d-background" data-parallax="scroll"></div>
    <div class="mt-auto container position-relative">
    <div id="searchbartextandtitle" class="col-auto align-items-center">
        <h1 id="searchtitle" class="entity-title">Search for movies, actors etc...</h1>
        <div class="dropdown">
        <input id="searchbar" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="search" value=""/>
            <div id="cleardiv" style="position: absolute">
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <div data-bind="foreach: personData">
                        <a data-bind="attr: { href: url}"><p data-bind="text: name"></p></a>
                </div>
                <div data-bind="foreach: titleData">
                        <a data-bind="attr: { href: url}"><p data-bind="text: primaryTitle"></p></a>
                </div>
                <div data-bind="foreach: genreData">
                        <a data-bind="attr: { href: url}"><p data-bind="text: name"></p></a>
                </div>
                <div data-bind="foreach: professionData">
                        <a data-bind="attr: { href: url}"><p data-bind="text: professionName"></p></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="top-block-head text-uppercase" style="text-align:center;">
        <h2 class="display-4">
            Featured
            <span class="text-theme">Movies</span>
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    top: 100px;
}

#searchbar.form-control{
    border: 2px solid grey;
    top: 30%;
    width: 70%;
    height:50px;
    color: #333333;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration-style: solid;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align:center !important;
    justify-content: space-around;
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: static;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.searchcontainer{
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center !important;
    align-items: center !important;
    display: block;
}
#searchbardiv.col-auto.align-items-center{
    background: rgba(255,138,0,0.7);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.85), rgba(0,0,0,0.85)) !important;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.85), rgba(0,0,0,0.85)) !important;
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.85), rgba(0,0,0,0.85)) !important;
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.85), rgba(0,0,0,0.85)) !important;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.85), rgba(0,0,0,0.85)) !important;
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

#searchbartextandtitle.col-auto.align-items-center{
    height: 300px;
    justify-content: center !important;
    align-items: center !important;
    display: block;
}

#searchtitle.entity-title{
    color: white;
    top: 30%;
    width: auto;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 10px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align:center;
    align-items: center;
    vertical-align: center !important;
    justify-content: space-around;
    float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it for now by adding a fixed width to the .dropdown-content container:

```
     .dropdown-content {
        display: static;
        position: absolute;
        width: 70%;
        right: 10%;
        left: 15%;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-height: 500px;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

The solution is pretty hardcoded, and therefore not optimal. But it works for now. I am still having problems scrolling through the search-results, now that they have a fixed height aswell. So if anyone's got pointers here, it'd be great!

Edit.
I added:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Which solved my problem, and i will therefore mark this as solved.